# Does GetPath() return cubic or quadratic bezier control points?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, graphics, vector

Microsoft's docs say:

> Specifies that the corresponding point
>   in lpPoints is a control point or
>   ending point for a Bèzier curve.
>            PT_BEZIERTO values always occur in sets of three. The point in
>   the path immediately preceding them
>   defines the starting point for the
>   Bèzier curve. The first two
>   PT_BEZIERTO points are the control
>   points, and the third PT_BEZIERTO
>   point is the ending (if hard-coded)
>   point.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144908%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

does this mean it returns cubic or quadratic curves?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a cubic with shared endpoints. p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3] make up the first segment; p[3], p[4], p[5], and p[6] make up the second segment. And so forth.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Just one more thing, how would this work if I was using Bezier handles?

Comment: @user146780, the handles are the points in the middle - in my example p[1] and p[2] for the first segment, and p[4] and p[5] for the second segment. I should also add that p[0] will be a PT_MOVETO rather than a PT_BEZIERTO.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say either, but depending on how you read it it could be either.

I'm leaning toward cubic rather than quadratic because cubic curves require four points and the documentation says

*start anchor*

> The point in the path immediately preceding ...

*two control points*

> PT_BEZIERTO values always occur in
>   sets of three. The first two are the
>   control points and ...

*terminating anchor*

> the third point is 
>   the ending point.

Here's a link describing the differences.

http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/bezierintro.html